# Correct way of parsing an ITE (if then else statement) SymPy object from a string

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to parse a SymPy expression object from strings, in particular, those of the type:

```
e = "ITE(1<2, K, X)"
```

It al works fine when running the following lines:

```
    from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
    import sympy as sp
    
    e = "ITE(1<2, K, X)"
    e = parse_expr(e, evaluate=False)
    print(f"e: {e}") # prints e: K
```

in which I can even substitute the symbol K for a value:

```
    k = sp.Symbol("K")
    e = e.subs(k, 1)
    print(f"e: {e}") # prints e: 1
```

The problem arrives when the expressions comes in the way:

```
    e = "ITE(1<2, (K+K), X)"
    e = parse_expr(e, evaluate=False)
    print(f"e: {e}")
```

From which I got the error: TypeError: expecting bool or Boolean, not `K + K`.

Which in principle is a little weird, since K was not a boolean in the previous example, jet it allowed me to parse it.

I have been playing around and could not find an acceptable way of doing it. [Piecewise](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise) seems to be a good starting point put it doesn't allows parsing from strings.

Is there a way to do this that doesnt implies changing the input string? this is, by changing "(K+K)" for lets say "A", and then evaluating A as (K+K) once the object is created.

Answer (score 1):

The ITE class is intended to be for symbolic Booleans and semantically represents the Boolean statement like `B if A else C` as `ITE(A, B, C)`. In SymPy an ordinary symbol can be considered either a Boolean or as representing a number. If you use the symbol like `K + K` then it cannot be a Boolean so `ITE` complains.

In your example what you should use is `Piecewise` like:

```
In [12]: parse_expr('Piecewise((K + K, z < t), (X, True))', evaluate=False)
Out[12]: 
⎧K + K  for t > z
⎨                
⎩  X    otherwise
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for `1 < 2` as the condition because the `evaluate=False` flag is not respected for `LessThan`:

```py
In [13]: parse_expr('Piecewise((K + K, 1 < 2), (X, True))', evaluate=False)
Out[13]: K + K
```

The fact that `evaluate=False` does not work as intended here is a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24288